# Can't compile open-source java game

Tags: java, compilation

I downloaded this open source game from https://github.com/SergeDavid/Advanced-Wars-Clone and want to compile it to check it out. However, I am still relatively new to java and haven't made my own program in this sort of layout. I cant seem to find a single file that I compile to get the whole program up and running.

I navigate to "Advanced-Wars-Clone-master\src\engine" in cmd, type "javac Game.java" and hit enter. The errors received are below.
Thanks.

```
Game.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        public static Map map;
                  ^
  symbol:   class Map
  location: class Game
Game.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
        public static Gui gui;
                  ^
  symbol:   class Gui
  location: class Game
Game.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
        public static LoadImages load;
                  ^
  symbol:   class LoadImages
  location: class Game
Game.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
        public static InputHandler input;
                  ^
  symbol:   class InputHandler
  location: class Game
Game.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
        public static Editor edit = new Editor();
                  ^
  symbol:   class Editor
  location: class Game
Game.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        public static Battle btl = new Battle();
                  ^
  symbol:   class Battle
  location: class Game
Game.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
        public static ErrorHandler error = new ErrorHandler();
                  ^
  symbol:   class ErrorHandler
  location: class Game
Game.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
        public static Pathfinding pathing = new Pathfinding();
                  ^
  symbol:   class Pathfinding
  location: class Game
Game.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
        public static ListData list;
                  ^
  symbol:   class ListData
  location: class Game
Game.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
        public static Save save = new Save();
                  ^
  symbol:   class Save
  location: class Game
Game.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
        public static ComputerBrain brain = new ComputerBrain();
                  ^
  symbol:   class ComputerBrain
  location: class Game
Game.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
        public static FileFinder finder = new FileFinder();
                  ^
  symbol:   class FileFinder
  location: class Game
Game.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
        public static ViewPoint view = new ViewPoint();
                  ^
  symbol:   class ViewPoint
  location: class Game
Game.java:49: error: package players does not exist
        public static List<players.Base> player = new        ArrayList<players.Base>();
                              ^
Game.java:50: error: package buildings does not exist
        public static List<buildings.Base> builds = new  ArrayList<buildings.Base>();
                                ^
Game.java:51: error: package units does not exist
        public static List<units.Base> units = new ArrayList<units.Base>();
                            ^
Game.java:53: error: package players does not exist
        public static List<players.Base> displayC = new ArrayList<players.Base>();
                              ^
Game.java:54: error: package buildings does not exist
        public static List<buildings.Base> displayB = new ArrayList<buildings.Base>();
                                ^
Game.java:55: error: package units does not exist
        public static List<units.Base> displayU = new ArrayList<units.Base>();
                            ^
Game.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
        public static Editor edit = new Editor();
                                    ^
  symbol:   class Editor
  location: class Game
Game.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        public static Battle btl = new Battle();
                                   ^
  symbol:   class Battle
  location: class Game
Game.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
        public static ErrorHandler error = new ErrorHandler();
                                           ^
  symbol:   class ErrorHandler
  location: class Game
Game.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
        public static Pathfinding pathing = new Pathfinding();
                                            ^
  symbol:   class Pathfinding
  location: class Game
Game.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
        public static Save save = new Save();
                                  ^
  symbol:   class Save
  location: class Game
Game.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
        public static ComputerBrain brain = new ComputerBrain();
                                            ^
  symbol:   class ComputerBrain
  location: class Game
Game.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
        public static FileFinder finder = new FileFinder();
                                          ^
  symbol:   class FileFinder
  location: class Game
Game.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
        public static ViewPoint view = new ViewPoint();
                                       ^
  symbol:   class ViewPoint
  location: class Game
Game.java:49: error: package players does not exist
        public static List<players.Base> player = new ArrayList<players.Base>();
                                                                   ^
Game.java:50: error: package buildings does not exist
        public static List<buildings.Base> builds = new ArrayList<buildings.Base>();
                                                                       ^
Game.java:51: error: package units does not exist
        public static List<units.Base> units = new ArrayList<units.Base>();
                                                              ^
Game.java:53: error: package players does not exist
        public static List<players.Base> displayC = new ArrayList<players.Base>();
                                                                     ^
Game.java:54: error: package buildings does not exist
        public static List<buildings.Base> displayB = new     ArrayList<buildings.Base>();
                                                                         ^
Game.java:55: error: package units does not exist
        public static List<units.Base> displayU = new ArrayList<units.Base>();
                                                                 ^
Game.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
                gui = new Gui(this);
                      ^
  symbol:   class Gui
  location: class Game
Game.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
                load = new LoadImages();
                       ^
  symbol:   class LoadImages
  location: class Game
Game.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
                map = new Map();
                      ^
  symbol:   class Map
  location: class Game
Game.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
                input = new InputHandler();
                        ^
  symbol:   class InputHandler
  location: class Game
Game.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
                list = new ListData();
                       ^
  symbol:   class ListData
  location: class Game
38 errors
```

Comment: Ahh thank you. I fiddled around a bit in eclipse after your comment and got it to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compile the project from command line, you need to first compile the classes on which other classes depend.

For example, in most of the sub-packages, there is a `Base.java` file. First compile that file, and then others.

At the end, compile the classes in the `Engine` sub-package.

If you can't figure out which file to compile first, then open it using an editor, and check which classes it uses. Then compile those classes first.

---

However, I would recommend you to import the project in and IDE and then compile it. Most of the IDEs automatically compile the required classes first.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working in eclipse. However out of interest, when I try it in the compiler, I only got one of the base.java files to compile. The others resulted in errors, even after successfully compiling one of the base.java files.